# Combining multiple IMPORTRANGE WITH QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to import data from multiple spreedsheet to one using query,

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1wMGl6qkQuz5ux42u4w8YAIEGiB3SN2b4EcgVJI-RTx4","DELIVERY DETAIL!$A$3:$I");
IMPORTRANGE("1A2dgmXRWbCzc9_jH38WruOMALsXrq8RFx7BcDW9Z8EI","DELIVERY DETAIL!$A$3:$I") }, 
"SELECT Col1,Col8,Col9 ",0)
```

the problem for me i get the data from one spreedsheet and receive nothing from the 2nd one,(i tried both of the importrange seperately without the query and it's working good), and it's importing the data from the source but when both of the importrange work it bring just data from 1st spreedsheet
BTW the name of the tabs are the same as i made duplicate the same spreedsheet

Answer (score 1):

you did not filter out empty rows. try:

```
=QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("1wMGl6qkQuz5ux42u4w8YAIEGiB3SN2b4EcgVJI-RTx4","DELIVERY DETAIL!$A$3:$I"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("1A2dgmXRWbCzc9_jH38WruOMALsXrq8RFx7BcDW9Z8EI","DELIVERY DETAIL!$A$3:$I")}, 
 "select Col1,Col8,Col9 
  where Col1 is not null", 0)
```